# Items within a container won't float to far left and right. Gaps are left on either side despite 0 padding

Tags: html, css

I have a `container` within my `banner` set to the same width as the body content.

I want a logo on the left side of the container (in line with the left body content) and text on the right side of the container (in line with the right of the body content)

```css
#bannerRow {
  width: 960px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#headerName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 29px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
}

#headerLogo {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner" id="banner">
  <div class="container" id="bannerRow">
    <img class="bannerlogo" src="~/Content/uct-logo-white.png" id="headerLogo">
    <h1 id="headerName"> Research Contracts and Innovation</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in both the logo and the text to have padding on their left and right side respectively, despite having set padding to 0.

How can I remove this padding?

Comment: You should use the `class` attribute instead of the `id`. This is because many reasons regarding scripts. 
You should therefore show your CSS assigned to your classes

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve] that actually shows your problem.

Comment: sounds as if the default margin for `body` still applies - add `html, body { margin: 0; }` to remove that margin.

Answer (score 0):

First you should update your question with all CSS for the shown elements and the elements containing those. There might be some values that are inherited.

Yet are you sure that it is your `padding` that are the trouble? What about your `margins`?

Setting right and left margins `auto` might do the trick. Maybe you should set the `margin-right` to `auto`. It might then set your element to the `left` then.

```
#headerName {
    color: white;
    font-size: 29px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    float: right;
    padding:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the paddings and margins by default from different browser, you can always reset all using a wildcard.

```
 *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue that you are facing can be solved by this. Instead of your CSS, write the following:

```
#bannerRow{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj4dk3ot/4/) is the fiddle for this answer.

I hope this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using a `flexbox` for `#bannerRow`. I have documented in the CSS code.

```css
#bannerRow {
  width: 960px;
  background-color: lightblue; /* for visibility only */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
}

#headerName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 29px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color: green; /* for visibility only */
  margin-left: auto; /* Push to the right */
}
```

```html
<div class="banner" id="banner">
  <div class="container" id="bannerRow">
    <img class="bannerlogo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" id="headerLogo">
    <h1 id="headerName"> Research Contracts and Innovation</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```